# How to send documented function to my server?

Tags: javascript, php

I have written a small and simple code that generates a person's username once they have entered their details (first and last name) in the text-box. So far, I have the script running when I enter the details in the input devices and when I press the button I am able to view the name. But I am having trouble trying to figure out how I can get the username to become an input (instead of div) and to be sent to my server?

To be more specific, I basically have two forms (which is not shown below), where a person would enter their details in the first form then go to their next form and enter additional details. Then once they are done, they submit it and it is taken to the server. So what I am trying to do is to keep the username hidden until all the details are sent to the server where it can be viewed.

Below is my code that has been condensed for simplification (with no major change).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.submitUsername = function() 
    {
        document.getElementById("username").innerHTML = "";

        var firstName = document.getElementById("fname").value;
        firstName = firstName.toUpperCase();
        firstName = firstName.substring(0,4);

        var lastName = document.getElementById("lname").value;
        lastName = lastName.toUpperCase();
        lastName = lastName.slice(lastName.length-4);

        var accountName = lastName + firstName;

        document.getElementById("username").innerHTML+= "Your Username: " + accountName + "<br /><br />";
    }
</script>
```

Form:

```
<body>
    <form method="post" action="http://***myserver***">
        <div>
            First name: <input type="text" id ="fname"/><br /><br />
            Last name: <input type = "text" id = "lname" /><br /><br />
        </div>
        <input type = "button" onClick = "submitUsername()" id = "submit" value = "Get your Username" /><br /><br />
        <div id = "username" name="username" >&nbsp;</div><br /><br />
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uhm, you are using a `<div>` with id *username*, and then you search for a DOM-element having this ID and insert the account-name. It is not weird you get the username "as a div".

What you want to do is adding a

```
<input type="hidden" id="username"></input>
```

in your form, and then fill that by:

```
document.getElementById("username").value = accountName;
```

and deleting the `<div id="username" ..` stuff.

*Bonus tip:* You don't want to use `&nbsp;` either, by the way. Just keep stuff empty.

Comment: I wish I can say "that did the trick" but I made the changes and now nothing happens.

Comment: Nope, forget it. I made a few adjustments and now it is working. Thanks for your help.